# Кнопка Skype в WPF

Tags: wpf, skype

Необходимо сделать чтобы в приложении WPF была кнопка (или просто картинка), при нажатии на которую открывался скайп и начинался чат с заранее заданным пользователем. Типа как когда нажимаю на гиперссылку mailto:example@gmail.com открывается имэйл клиент уже с введенным адресом, нужно такое же, только со скайпом) Кто знает как такое сделать, и возможно ли?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Оказалось все легко:

```
Process.Start("skype:echo123?chat");
```